# ERROR TypeError: can't convert true into String in webrick with Twilio response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm getting an error inside webrick and have no idea how to solve the problem. Rather than bloat the question with with reams of code, I've added the code after the question.

I'm using Twilio to generate automated phone messages, however, I don't know if the problem is related to the Twilio gem. From the research I've done, This is often related to some sort of gem incompatibiliy. Please see my **gemfile** below with the **versions** installed. You can also see the **error message** and the **webrick file** where the error occurs. Finally, here's the code that breaks

```
def response
  Rails.logger.debug '+ response' if PHONE_DEBUG
  Rails.logger.debug '* @question.text = ' + @question.text if PHONE_DEBUG

  if (@question.text =~ /hash|\#/i) != nil
    finish_on_key = '#'
  else
    finish_on_key = ''
  end

  Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say @question.text, voice: 'alice', language: 'en-AU'
    r.Gather finishOnKey: finish_on_key, timeout: PHONE_WAIT_TIME,
      action: NGROK + answers_path(@question.id) # Answer create
  end.to_xml
  Rails.logger.debug '- response' if PHONE_DEBUG
end
```

If you take a look at the **error message** file, you can see the `logger.debug` messages from the code above just before it explodes. When my rails application calls me, the code above runs when I pickup the phone. It should ask me a question (but it never does), then after I answer, it redirect to the answers path.

Webrick fails here,

```
body.each { |part|
  res.body << part
}
```

I ran `logger.debug` on the offending variables and found that `res.body` is a string and `part` is a boolean, so the message makes sense. Does anyone have any idea how this can be solved?

### Gemfile

```
*source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]

# Coffee script 1.9.0 doesn''t play well with Windows.  SMH
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'

# Tabbed Navigation goodies
gem 'tabulous'

# SMS and phone call support
gem 'twilio-ruby'

# Validate phone numbers easily
gem 'phony_rails'

# Secure login
gem 'devise'

group :development, :teachinator, :careinator do
  gem 'rails-erd'     # ERD - Entity-Relationship Diagrams for documentation
  gem 'annotator'     # Annotator - Adds comments to Model files to from DB info
  gem 'faker', '1.7.2'# Helps generate db:seed data
end*
```

### Versions

```
*d:\svn_branch\rails\jobinator>bundle install
Using rake 11.3.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.5
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using choice 0.2.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.8.0
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using colored 1.2
Using currencies 0.4.2
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jwt 1.5.6
Using phony 2.2.14
Using bundler 1.13.6
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using ruby-graphviz 1.2.2
Using sass 3.2.19
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using faker 1.7.2
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mail 2.6.3
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 2.7.1
Using countries 0.9.3
Using twilio-ruby 4.13.0
Using sprockets 2.12.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.1.8
Using tzinfo-data 1.2015.6
Using actionview 4.1.8
Using activemodel 4.1.8
Using jbuilder 2.3.1
Using phony_rails 0.6.1
Using actionpack 4.1.8
Using activerecord 4.1.8
Using actionmailer 4.1.8
Using railties 4.1.8
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2
Using annotator 0.0.10
Using rails-erd 1.5.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using responders 1.1.2
Using jquery-rails 3.1.3
Using rails 4.1.8
Using sass-rails 4.0.5
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using devise 3.5.10
Using tabulous 2.1.3
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 60 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

d:\svn_branch\rails\jobinator>*
```

### Error Message

```
******** CreateResponse.for
+ response
* @question.text = Please press any key to continue.
- response
Completed 200 OK in 143ms (Views: 0.0ms | ActiveRecord: 105.0ms)
[2017-03-06 11:52:37] ERROR TypeError: can't convert true into String
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:73:in `block in service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:72:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

### Webrick

```
*require 'webrick'
require 'stringio'
require 'rack/content_length'

module Rack
  module Handler
    class WEBrick < ::WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
      def self.run(app, options={})
        options[:BindAddress] = options.delete(:Host) if options[:Host]
        options[:Port] ||= 8080
        @server = ::WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(options)
        @server.mount "/", Rack::Handler::WEBrick, app
        yield @server  if block_given?
        @server.start
      end

      def self.valid_options
        {
          "Host=HOST" => "Hostname to listen on (default: localhost)",
          "Port=PORT" => "Port to listen on (default: 8080)",
        }
      end

      def self.shutdown
        @server.shutdown
        @server = nil
      end

      def initialize(server, app)
        super server
        @app = app
      end

      def service(req, res)
        env = req.meta_vars
        env.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }

        rack_input = StringIO.new(req.body.to_s)
        rack_input.set_encoding(Encoding::BINARY) if rack_input.respond_to?(:set_encoding)

        env.update({"rack.version" => Rack::VERSION,
                     "rack.input" => rack_input,
                     "rack.errors" => $stderr,

                     "rack.multithread" => true,
                     "rack.multiprocess" => false,
                     "rack.run_once" => false,

                     "rack.url_scheme" => ["yes", "on", "1"].include?(ENV["HTTPS"]) ? "https" : "http"
                   })

        env["HTTP_VERSION"] ||= env["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]
        env["QUERY_STRING"] ||= ""
        unless env["PATH_INFO"] == ""
          path, n = req.request_uri.path, env["SCRIPT_NAME"].length
          env["PATH_INFO"] = path[n, path.length-n]
        end
        env["REQUEST_PATH"] ||= [env["SCRIPT_NAME"], env["PATH_INFO"]].join

        status, headers, body = @app.call(env)
        begin
          res.status = status.to_i
          headers.each { |k, vs|
            if k.downcase == "set-cookie"
              res.cookies.concat vs.split("\n")
            else
              # Since WEBrick won't accept repeated headers,
              # merge the values per RFC 1945 section 4.2.
              res[k] = vs.split("\n").join(", ")
            end
          }
          body.each { |part|
            res.body << part
          }
        ensure
          body.close  if body.respond_to? :close
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can't see any of your links. I think they are private files/links of your DropBox account

Comment: Please add the sections of your code here instead of referencing them elsewhere. This might turn out to be a problem for someone else and if the links are dead then the question becomes vague.

Comment: Just looking at that now.

Comment: Are the links all working now?

Comment: All done. Is that better?

Comment: I decided to remove all links as per @vee comments. I originally had links to `"gemfile"`, `"versions"` etc in dropbox. The stack overflow post is useless if the links are broken. **DO NOT LINK TO EXTERNAL SITES** like dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking the error line [on the rack source code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb#L73), it seems that it's trying to append the response to the body string. In your `response` code, your last sentence is a boolean method:

```
def response
  # ...

  Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    # ...
  end.to_xml
  Rails.logger.debug '- response' if PHONE_DEBUG
end
```

Instead of sending the Twilio xml, you're returning the `Rails.logger.debug` result, which is `true`.

Change it to something like this:

```
def response
  Rails.logger.debug '+ response' if PHONE_DEBUG
  Rails.logger.debug '* @question.text = ' + @question.text if PHONE_DEBUG

  if (@question.text =~ /hash|\#/i) != nil
    finish_on_key = '#'
  else
    finish_on_key = ''
  end

  # -- Store it in a variable --
  xml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say @question.text, voice: 'alice', language: 'en-AU'
    r.Gather finishOnKey: finish_on_key, timeout: PHONE_WAIT_TIME,
      action: NGROK + answers_path(@question.id) # Answer create
  end.to_xml
  Rails.logger.debug '- response' if PHONE_DEBUG

  # -- Return the stored xml --
  xml
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it